# Center content of a scrollable div with display:block vertically

Tags: css

I am trying to center text vertically inside a scrollable element with display: block. The code works ok in case there are multiple lines, but if there are only 1 or 2 lines, they just stick to the top.
Changing display:block to something else would break the layout of the page and require spending around a week to rewrite all the styles and make it work again. Is there a way to avoid this?

Here is the code:

```
.wrapper {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 55px;
}

<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    .....text content.....
  </div>
</div>
```

Example code:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GIZNNLYQBPUE

Basically, what I need is to center the content in case there are not enough lines to fill all the height of a parent div.

Comment: display:flex on wrapper + margin:auto 0 on inner div (flex will not break the layout of your page because it behave the same way as block from the outside)

Comment: OR `min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;` on the inner div without touching the wrapper

Comment: I have added 5 duplicates, not only one